# C programming ... Why "return" statement give only one value in this code?

Tags: c, return

I'm newbie for coding C.  I'm trying to write a program which is adding a value at the first position the array. As shown below, `append` function must return more than one value.

When I use `printf("%d ", array[c])` statement in this function, there is no problem and I get the values what I want.

However, when I use `return s;` statement in this function, it gives only one value, although it must give same values with `printf("%d ", array[c])` statement.

When I run this code with `printf("%d ", array[c])`, the output is:

> 25, 5, 8, 555, 99

When I run this code with `return s`, the output is;

> 25

Why there is a different between two statements? I don’t need to print the values on screen.  I need to use `return` statement. Please help me for this…

```
#include <stdio.h>

int append(int array[]){

          int  position, c, s, len=4, value=25; 

          position=1;

          for (c = len - 1; c >= position-1; c--){
              array[c+1] = array[c];
              }
          array[position-1] = value;
          for (c = 0; c <= len; c++){

                //return array[c]; // <-- why this give only one value???   
                printf("%d ", array[c]);    //<--  this print the all value !!! 
              }          
}

int main(){

    int kar[]= {5, 8, 555, 99};

    printf("%d", append(kar));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `return` statement in `append` function here.

Comment: Why does `append` need to return anything? Possibly you should just mutate the array instead? I suspect you are missing a lot of fundamentals, and explaining all of them would be beyond the scope of what can be the answer to one question.

Comment: There is no `return s`. `s` is not used at all.

Comment: there is return statement but I write it as comment line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `array` to the function, which is actually passing a pointer to the first element of the array.  This means that changes to the array in the function also will appear in the calling function since it's the same array.

You don't need to return anything.  Just print the contents of the array in `main`.

Also, an array of size 4 has indexes from 0 to 3.  Right now you're writing past the end of the array.  You need to change your function to prevent that.  You can't just write past the end of the array to make it bigger.  The size is fixed.

```
void append(int array[]){
      int  position, c, s, len=4, value=25; 
      position=1;

      for (c = len - 2; c >= position-1; c--){
          array[c+1] = array[c];
      }
      array[position-1] = value;
}

int main() {
    int kar[]= {5, 8, 555, 99};

    append(kar);

    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++){
        printf("%d ", kar[c]);
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response but code gives:  [Error] 'array' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Kemal That should be `kar`.  Updated.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

void append(int array[]){
      int  position, c, s, len=4, value=25; 
      position=1;

      for (c = len - 2; c >= position-1; c--){
          array[c+1] = array[c];
      }
      array[position-1] = value;
}

int main() {
 
    

    int kar[]= {5, 8, 555, 99};

    append(kar);

    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++){
        printf("%d ", array[c]);
    }       
    return 0;
}

Comment: excuse me please but it gives same error...

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! OK. excuse me this my mistake..... thanks again and again......

Answer (score 0):

In C, each function must return exactly one value. (It can be `void` if it doesn't need to return anything.)

If you want multiple results from a function, there are two ways to achieve this.

**Option one:** in your function, allocate some kind of structure for holding multiple values (often, but not necessarily, an array) and make the *one* return value from your function be a *pointer* to that structure. The caller of the function will usually be responsible for cleaning up that structure when it is done with it, using `free` for example.

**Option two:** have your function take a pointer to some kind of a container for multiple values (often, but not necessarily, an array) and "return" the results by adding them into the container.

In either case, it is still the responsibility of the caller (`main` in this case) to do something meaningful with each of the values, for example by using a `for` loop to print them all out.

Comment: It is simpler to return a structure (not a pointer to a structure) that contains two values.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run this code with "printf("%d ", array[c])", the output is;
>
> 25, 5, 8, 555, 99

That's because you're calling the `printf` statement as part of a *loop*:

```
for (c = 0; c <= len; c++){
  printf("%d ", array[c]);    
}
```

IOW, you're calling

```
printf("%d ", array[0]); // prints 25
printf("%d ", array[1]); // prints 5
printf("%d ", array[2]); // prints 555
printf("%d ", array[3]); // prints 99
```

`printf` with the `%d` modifier *cannot* print an entire array of `int` - it can only print a single `int` value at a time.

Note that your `return` statement

```
return array[c];
```

only returns a *single element* of the array (from within the loop, that would be element 0).

As other people have mentioned, you don't need to *return* anything (except for maybe the new array size).

But this brings up another problem - given your declaration

```
int kar[]= {5, 8, 555, 99};
```

`kar` *cannot* hold more than 4 values - it cannot be extended to hold any more.  You will either need to declare `kar` with a size that's bigger than 4:

```
int kar[10] = {5, 8, 555, 99};
```

or you will need to allocate that memory dynamically and extend it as necessary:

```
size_t arr_size = 4;
int *kar = malloc( sizeof *kar * arr_size );

kar[0] = 5;
kar[1] = 8;
kar[2] = 555;
kar[3] = 99;

/**
 * Add 25 to the beginning of the array
 */
append( 25, &kar, &arr_size );
```

and then in your `append` function:

```
void append( int val, int **array, size_t *size )
{
  /** 
   * Extend the array size by 1.  We assign the result to a temporary in 
   * case realloc fails and returns a NULL - this way we won't lose our 
   * reference the the original memory.  
   *
   * In practice, we would not extend the array one element at a time (realloc
   * can be an expensive operation, so you want to minimize the number of
   * times you call it), but I'm trying to keep the example as simple as
   * I can.  
   */
  int *tmp = realloc( *array, *size + 1 );

  if ( tmp )
  {
    /**
     * Realloc succeeded - update the size and assign tmp back to
     * *array (this is why we needed to pass `array` as an `int **`;
     * we need to update the pointer value).  
     */
    (*size)++;
    *array = tmp;

    /**
     * Shift all elements up one.
     */
    for ( size_t c = *size - 1; c > 0; c-- )
      (*array)[c] = (*array)[c-1];           // we don't want to index into array, we want
                                             // to index into what array *points to*
    /**
     * Add the new value to the beginning of the array
     */
    (*array)[0] = val;
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Could not extend input array, contents left unchanged\n" );
  }
}
```

When you're done, be sure to deallocate that memory at the end of `main`:

```
free( kar );
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Excuse me but when I rearranged my code as you say, I meet this error :[Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]. int *tmp = realloc( *array, *size + 1 ); this line causes the error.

Comment: @Kemal: you may need to `#include <stdlib.h>`